# How to get selected input:radio

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button, checked

How come this works.

```
$('input:checked')
```

and this won't?

```
$('input').is(':checked')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second version should [use `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
$('input').filter(':checked')
```

It seems like `.is()` should work since there's [a `.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/). But `.not()` is actually the opposite of `.filter()`.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for, which I need for chaining purposes

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if *any* radio button on the page is selected? No need to do that, there's always one that's selected (radio button = exactly one option selected).

Want to test if a radio button with a certain ID is selected?

```
$('#your-radio-button').is(':checked')
```

Want a list of all checked radio buttons? This returns a jQuery object containing the radio inputs.

```
$('input:radio:checked')
```

If you want to restrict it to inputs with a certain name:

```
$('input[name=something]:radio:checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Define works. One returns a list and the other returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name='radioName']:checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.Its worked & tested also.

```
$("input[type=radio]:checked").val()

$("input:radio:checked").val()

$("input:radio").filter(":checked").val()
```

Or
You can get help from this sample
http://daxpanganiban.com/javascript/get-value-of-radio-button-using-jquery

Cheers!